# The 2nd digit of my first number has the same value as the 1st digit of the 2nd number. I don't know why

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I am new to assembly language. I am trying to add 2 integers which is only 2 digits, but whenever I try to access my second digit in num1 it mysteriously accesses the first digit of num2. I need help! I really don't know why. I'm using TASM btw.

This is my code.

```
;-----------------------
.model small
.stack 
.data

num db ?
num2 db ?
result db ?

prompt1 db "Enter 1st number: $"
prompt2 db "Enter 2nd number: $"
prompt3 db "Addition: $"

.code

main proc

;use the data segment
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax

;-------input first number--------------------  

;setcursor
mov ah, 02
mov dh, 00h
mov dl, 00h
int 10h

mov ah, 09
lea dx, prompt1
int 21h

mov cx, 02
lea si, num

loop1:
    mov ah, 07
    int 21h

    cmp al, 0Dh
    je outA

    cmp al, '0'
    jge True_A
    jmp false

    True_A:
        cmp al, '9'
        jle True_B
        jmp false


    True_B:
        mov ah, 02
        mov dl, al
        int 21h

        mov [si], al
    jmp next

    next:
    inc si
    dec cx      

    false:

jnz loop1

outA:

mov bl, '$'
mov [si], bl

;--------input 2nd number-----------------------------

;setcursor
mov ah, 02
mov dh, 02h
mov dl, 00h
int 10h

mov ah, 09
lea dx, prompt2
int 21h

mov cx, 02
lea di, num2

loop2:
    mov ah, 07
    int 21h

    cmp al, 0Dh
    je outB

    cmp al, '0'
    jge True_C
    jmp falseA

    True_C:
        cmp al, '9'
        jle True_D
        jmp falseA

    True_D:
        mov ah, 02
        mov dl, al
        int 21h

        mov [di], al
    jmp nextA

    nextA:
    inc di
    dec cx      

    falseA:
jnz loop2

outB:

mov bl, '$'
mov [di], bl

;-------------------------------------- 

mov ah, 02
mov dh, 05h
mov dl, 00h
int 10h

mov ah, 02
mov dl, num + 1
int 21h


mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

Comment: The _mystery_ is that you allocated a single byte for your number, so obviously the second digit will overlap the second number. You could use `db ?, ?` or `dw ?` instead. You should do that for all three numbers, of course.

Comment: I did what you said. I changed all 3 numbers

`num1 dw ?
num2 dw ?
result dw ?`

but when I tried printing num1, it printed the 2 numbers instead.

`mov ah, 09
lea dx, num1
int 21h`

Comment: As you well know, int21/09 requires a `$` sign at the end of the string that is printed. You can embed that by doing `db ?, ?, '$'` for example.

Comment: Wow. thanks, I think realized my mistakes now. :D

Comment: @random: There are some links that might help debugging future problems at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  To catch this on your own, you would have had to have noticed that the pointers for your two variables were too close together.  Unlike a lot of asm-debugging questions we get here, this one wouldn't be that easy to spot single-stepping with a debugger and watching register values change.

Answer (score 3):

```
num db ?
num2 db ?
result db ?
```

Both your routines to input a 2-digit number perform 3 byte sized writes to memory. First digit, second digit, and then a **$** character.  But you defined only a single byte of storage for each number. Just change the relevant defines.

```
num    db ?,?,?
num2   db ?,?,?
result db ?,?,?,?
```

I would advice to give an extra byte of storage to *result* since it's possible for the addition to have 3 digits. Max value would be 99 + 99 = 198